# Using PHP usort with conditional results

Tags: php, arrays, usort

Long story short, I need to sort an array of objects using usort, and I need to tell usort which fields in the objects to sort by.

The obvious solution is to create tens of separate usort sorting functions, but this seems *sort of* redundant and ugly. Most of the time, objects will be sorted by input from $_GET, but not always, so I don't want to sort by $_GET variables directly.

Is it possible for the usort function to use the current class' sorting function? Something like this

```
<?php

    class myClass
    {
        public $myArray;
        private $by;

        public function filter($by)
        {
            $this->by = $by;
            usort($this->myArray, /* Somehow point to the following function: */ );
        }

        private function srt($a, $b)
        {
            $c = $this->by; // <- reaching a third variable

            // ...
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pass an array of the object and the method name to `usort()`:

```
usort($this->myArray, array($this, 'srt'));
```

**EDIT:** I've tested and found that this will work with private methods as long as you call `usort()` in the same class that contains the private method.

Answer (score 0):

Other ways you can call usort function from inside a method.

```
usort($this->myArray, 'myClass::srt');
usort($this->myArray, array(self::class, 'srt'));
```